# Can we Runtime.getRuntime().exec("groovy");

Tags: java, groovy, processbuilder

I installed Groovy.

[image]

And I am trying to run groovy scripts from a command prompt that I created using Java, like so:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("groovy");
```

So if I type in "groovy" to the command line, this is what I get:

```
>>>groovy
Cannot run program "groovy": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what might be going wrong? Should I just use Groovy's implementation of exec? Like:

```
def processBuilder=new ProcessBuilder("ls")
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true)
processBuilder.directory(new File("Your Working dir"))  // <--
def process = processBuilder.start()
```

My guess is that it wouldn't matter whether using Java's implementation or Groovy's implementation.

So how do I run a groovy script?

Comment: Have you added Groovy to your Path Environment variable?

Comment: Why don't you [run it directly](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy); that's what it's designed to do...

Comment: @Blaine, yes, I verified that.

Comment: I restarted my windows machine, and NOW it works. Magic.

Comment: consider deleting question as it is unlikely to ever help anyone

Comment: @michael that's a good idea

Comment: I don't know how to delete a question

Answer (score 2):

The way originally described in the question above calling the groovy executable invokes a second Java runtime instance and class loader while the efficient way is to embed the Groovy script directly into the Java runtime as a Java class and invoke it.

Here are three ways to execute a Groovy script from Java:

1) Simplest way is using [GroovyShell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html):

Here is an example Java main program and target Groovy script to invoke:

== TestShell.java ==

```
import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;

// call groovy expressions from Java code
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("input", "world");
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
Object retVal = shell.evaluate(new File("hello.groovy"));
// prints "hello world"
System.out.println("x=" + binding.getVariable("x")); // 123
System.out.println("return=" + retVal); // okay
```

== hello.groovy ==

```
println "Hello $input"
x = 123 // script-scoped variables are available via the GroovyShell
return "ok"
```

2) Next is to use [GroovyClassLoader](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html) to parse the script into a class then create an instance of it. This approach treats the Groovy script as a class and invokes methods on it as on any Java class.

```
GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader();
Class clazz = gcl.parseClass(new File("hello.groovy");
Object aScript = clazz.newInstance();
// probably cast the object to an interface and invoke methods on it
```

3) Finally, you can create [GroovyScriptEngine](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.html) and pass in objects as variables using binding. This runs the Groovy script as a script and passes in input using binding variables as opposed to calling explicit methods with arguments.

Note: This third option is for developers who want to embed groovy scripts into a server and have them reloaded on modification.

```
import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine;

String[] roots = new String[] { "/my/groovy/script/path" };
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(roots);
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("input", "world");
gse.run("hello.groovy", binding);
System.out.println(binding.getVariable("output"));
```

Note: You must include the groovy_all jar in your CLASSPATH for these approaches to work.

Reference: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy